# What would be the probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Lets say you have tossed a fair coin 100 times. What is the probability that you got at least 10 tails?

Comment: You have to use the binomial distribution

Comment: Or an approximation with normal distribution having mean $np=50$ and variance $np(1-p)=25$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800997/. The duplicates were easy to find. Please make more effort to search existing questions before posting a new one.